# Magento - Seo Layered Navigation Plugin Issue in 1.13

Tags: magento, magento-1.13

We've recently upgraded to 1.13 on our site and the only plugin that does not seem to work is the "Seo Layered Navigation" by "Ecommerce Team".  I have contacted their team, but they do not support 1.13 yet.  Everything in the plugin works great, except for the actual ajax calls for filtered results.  The "is_ajax" component does not seemed to be picked up for any reason.

site.com/catename/filter/manufacturer/manuwesearchingfor?is_ajax=1
always returns a 404 error.

The observer for ajax is not being executed for some reason.  In the config.xml of the plugin we have:

```
 <frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
        <observers>
            <setfilterspagetitle>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>ecommerceteam_sln/observer</class>
            <method>setPageTitle</method>
            </setfilterspagetitle>
        </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
        <controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_category_view>
        <observers>
            <init_ajax_request>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>ecommerceteam_sln/observer</class>
            <method>initAjax</method>
            </init_ajax_request>
        </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_category_view>
        <controller_action_layout_render_before_catalogsearch_result_index>
        <observers>
            <init_ajax_request>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>ecommerceteam_sln/observer</class>
            <method>initAjax</method>
            </init_ajax_request>
        </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_render_before_catalogsearch_result_index>
    </events>
```

I cannot find any documentation on why the change from 1.12 to 1.13 would have removed one of these observers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was the new redirect engine in Magento EE.  The "Ecommerce Team" was awesome and had a fix in a day!